# Fastify cant post or get Data

Tags: node.js, fastify

acctualy, i  dont know why its not work  but i guess the flow is right. when server running well on port 3000,  im trying get  data using postman (http://localhost:3000/api/user/)  but i cant  get anythng from postman

or you can view my code for more detail  : https://github.com/wildy13/Nuxt3

this is a  structur  directory.

```
Api
--User
----controller
----index
----model
config
--index
router.js
index.js
```

this is api/user/index.

```
const Fastify = require("fastify");
const { createUser, getUsers } = require("./controller");
const fastify = Fastify();


fastify.post("/", async (request, reply) => {
  try {
    const newUser = await createUser(request.body); 
    console.log("Data pengguna yang baru dibuat:", newUser);
    reply.status(201).send(newUser);
  } catch (error) {
    reply.status(500).send({ error: "Internal Server Error" });
  }
});

fastify.get("/", async (request, reply) => {
  try {
    const users = await getUsers();
    console.log("Data users:", users);
    reply.send(users);
  } catch (error) {
    reply.status(500).send({ error: "Internal Server Error" });
  }
});

module.exports = fastify;
```

router.js

```
const user = require('./api/user')

const router = (fastify) => {
    fastify.register(user, { prefix: 'api/user'})
}

module.exports = router
```

index.js

```
const Fastify = require('fastify');
const fastifyCors = require('@fastify/cors');
const router = require('./router');

const fastify = Fastify();
fastify.register(fastifyCors, {
    origin: '*',
    methods: 'GET, PUT, POST, DELETE',
  });

fastify.register(router); 
const { sequelize, config: { host, port } } = require('./config');

const User = require('./api/user/model')

const connect = async () => {
    try {
        await sequelize.authenticate();
        console.log('connection has been estabilished successfully')
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}


const start = async () => {
    try {
        router(fastify);
        // User.sync({ force:true  })
        fastify.listen ({ port, host }, () => console.log(`Server Running on Port ${port}`));
        await connect();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}

start()
```

the server running well using port 3000, but when i  using postman for get data, i  cant get data (before, i've data)

so i expect i get data

Comment: Are you getting any errors related to the database or anything? Also please share the controller,  model & config file code. That will be helpful in identifying the issue.

Comment: @JavascriptHuppTechnologies no

Comment: @JavascriptHuppTechnologies https://github.com/wildy13/Nuxt3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

index.js

```
const Fastify = require('fastify');
const fastifyCors = require('@fastify/cors');
const router = require('./router');

const fastify = Fastify();
fastify.register(fastifyCors, {
    origin: '*',
    methods: 'GET, PUT, POST, DELETE',
  });

fastify.register(router); 
const { sequelize, config: { host, port } } = require('./config');

const User = require('./api/user/model')

const connect = async () => {
    try {
        await sequelize.authenticate();
        console.log('connection has been estabilished successfully')
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}


const start = async () => {
    try {
        fastify.listen ({ port, host }, () => console.log(`Server Running on Port ${port}`));
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}

start()
```

router.js

```
const user = require('./api/user')

const route = async (fastify) => {
    fastify.register(user, { prefix: 'api/user'})
};

module.exports = route
```

api/user/controller.js

```
const User = require('./model')

const createUser = async (req, res) => {
    const {
        username
    } = req.body

    try {
        const newUser = new User({
            username
        })

        const user = await newUser.save();
        res.status(200).send(user)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}

const getUsers = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const user = await User.findAll({
            attributes: ['username']
        })
        res.status(200).send(user);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

module.exports = { createUser, getUsers}
```

api.user/index.js

```
const { createUser, getUsers } = require("./controller");

const users = async (fastify) => {
  fastify.route({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/',
    handler: createUser
  });

  fastify.route({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/',
    handler: getUsers
  });

};

module.exports = users;
```

Comment: [link](https://i.postimg.cc/pdLMRD5D/Screenshot-2023-09-18-134705.png)

still cant get data, but acctualy ive one data on mysql

Comment: i dont know why, but i  dont get any err.

Comment: thank you so much, now i know whats different express with fastify